# How many ways are there to construct a string of $3$ digits if numbers cannot be repeated?

Tags: combinatorics

My question: "How many ways are there to construct a string of $3$ digits if numbers cannot be repeated?"

After a few days of scratching head, I still have no idea how to solve it. May anyone give a hint to help me think through and keep going to the answer, please?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hint: in how many way can we choose the first digit? Then after the second digit? Then after the third digit?

Comment: After a few days? It only takes a few minutes to write them all down!

Comment: Yup, if you are confused about how to count a set, you can always try first just to write down some examples and count yourself.  If 3 digits is too many, try the problem for just 2 digits.  Then think about it and see if you see any way to count it faster.

Comment: Thank you guys! I solved the problem. It is very simple when looking to another angle: order 3 digits from a set from 0  to 9. So the answer is P(10,3) = 720.    Previously, I got the 1st question "How many ways are there to construct a string of 3 digits if numbers CAN be repeated?" . The solution(multiplication principle) I found for this blocked my mind from thinking another angle when the question twisted.